# Adding caption label to UImageView in Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am completely new to iOS development. I have never wrote a piece of code in my life. But I am attempting to follow this tutorial [here](http://swiftiostutorials.com/tutorial-using-uicollectionview-uicollectionviewflowlayout/). I have successfully completed the tutorial, but I am looking to mod the code a little bit.

- How can I add a text 'Title' under each Image loaded?
- And also how do i go about changing the colors of the image border
  and app background?

**ViewController**:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var galleryItems: [GalleryItem] = []
    var listOfDescriptions = [String]()

    // MARK: -
    // MARK: - View Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initGalleryItems()
        collectionView.reloadData()
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
        UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }

    private func initGalleryItems() {

        var items = [GalleryItem]()
        let inputFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("items", ofType: "plist")

        let inputDataArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: inputFile!)

        for inputItem in inputDataArray as! [Dictionary<String, String>] {
            let galleryItem = GalleryItem(dataDictionary: inputItem)
            items.append(galleryItem)
        }

        galleryItems = items
    }
    private func populateList() {
        listOfDescriptions.append("Valhaha is a flavor");
        listOfDescriptions.append("Unicorns blood is made from dead unicorns. Harry Potter in this bit");
    }
    private func getDescription(position: Int) -> String {
        return listOfDescriptions[position]
    }

    // MARK: -
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return galleryItems.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("GalleryItemCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GalleryItemCollectionViewCell

        cell.setGalleryItem(galleryItems[indexPath.row])
        return cell

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        let commentView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "GalleryItemCommentView", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GalleryItemCommentView

        commentView.commentLabel.text = "Supplementary view of kind \(kind)"

        return commentView
    }

    // MARK: -
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "didSelectItemAtIndexPath:", message: "Indexpath = \(indexPath)", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Destructive, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(alertAction)

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: -
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewFlowLayout

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let picDimension = self.view.frame.size.width / 4.0
        return CGSizeMake(picDimension, picDimension)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        let leftRightInset = self.view.frame.size.width / 14.0
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, leftRightInset, 0, leftRightInset)
    }
}
```

**GalleryItemCollectionCellView**:

```
import UIKit

class GalleryItemCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet var itemImageView: UIImageView!

func setGalleryItem(item:GalleryItem) {
    itemImageView.image = UIImage(named: item.itemImage)
}
```

}

Comment: You want to add label below or above the image?

Comment: Add an `UILabel` var to into the `GalleryItemCollectionCellView`. Also add a label below the image view and make IBOutlet connection with created label var.

Comment: @IntelliDev what about xcode of you now. Do you using swift 2?

Comment: I dont know swift syntax and I am away from my machine. Can't help much.

Comment: @vien vu yes I'm using the latest xcode with swift 2

Comment: @IntelliDev check my answer, maybe it will work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your project you want add label below image view, you should add to cell on storyboard like this:

[image]

Drage outlet to cell:

[image]

Change setdata function:

```
func setGalleryItem(item:GalleryItem) {
    itemImageView.image = UIImage(named: item.itemImage)
    itemNameLabel.text = item.itemImage
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
}
```

And in `viewController` re-calculate size of cell:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let picDimension = self.view.frame.size.width / 4.0
    return CGSizeMake(picDimension, picDimension + 31)
}
```

depen you want you can change 31 to size of label you want.

I see border you want is background of cell. so add it into the set item above. If you just want border aroud image view: you can use:

```
func setGalleryItem(item:GalleryItem) {
    itemImageView.image = UIImage(named: item.itemImage)
    itemNameLabel.text = item.itemImage
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    itemImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    itemImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
}
```

choose the wait you want.

Change color of view you add into `viewDidload`

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initGalleryItems()
    collectionView.reloadData()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()//change color view
}
```

Here is demo from your source:  [Demo](https://github.com/vienvu89/DemoCollectionView)

Comment: this is awesome. how do i set the caption from a list of strings based on position however? sorry i forgot to include that detail in my question.

Comment: ? I don't understand what you said

Comment: solution 1: you can save in model `GalleryItem`. you will add a variable `itemlabel` or something name and  when set  item in `newGalleryItem(dataDictionary:Dictionary<String,String>) -> GalleryItem` you and assign in there. in `func setGalleryItem(item:GalleryItem) ` you can get from model label you want.

Comment: solution 2: in `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` after line: ` cell.setGalleryItem(galleryItems[indexPath.row])` you can acess label via `cell.itemNameLabel` and assign title you want depend on indexPath

Comment: @IntelliDev check my new comment.

Comment: Thank you. once i run your original demo ill mark best answer if it works. youve been awesome!

Answer (score 5):

To Change Border color:

```
imageView.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.anyColor().CGColor
```

It will change your Image view border color.

Following code will set label on Image View:

```
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(x, y, width,hight))
label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
label.text = "I'am a test label"
self.imageview.addSubview(label)
```

**Here's the Updated Method:**

```
func setGalleryItem(item:GalleryItem) 
{
    itemImageView.image = UIImage(named: item.itemImage)
    //This for imageview border color
    itemImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.anyColor().CGColor

    //This for setting label in image view
    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(x, y, width,hight))
    label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.text = "I'am a test label"
    itemImageView.addSubview(label)
}
```

Comment: Where do i add this?

Comment: do you have use collectionview?

Comment: yes i use collection view. i updated my post to include my ViewController class

Comment: i could not find imageview in your code.first you need to take one imageview in collectionview  like this link   http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/

Comment: its called GalleryItemCollectionViewCell. i updated to include that code.

Comment: I add Updated Method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100204/discussion-between-imjaydeep-and-intelli-dev).